# How do I increase the time Visual Studio is allowed to be unresponsive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to develop an application in C# communicating via OData with Microsoft's Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations solution. This uses a large (900,000+ lines) file produced by Microsoft's OData V4 Client Generator extension (V2.4.0).

Whenever I accidentally step into code in this file while debugging, or try to look at a definition in it (whether the application is running or not), or otherwise just open the file, Visual Studio 2017 (currently version 15.5.6) will become unresponsive and be restarted a few seconds later.

Visual Studio 2015 used to start getting various panels no being refreshed and flickering as complete blank before it failed. Visual Studio 2017 just locks up.

I have wondered if the timeout before it gets restarted could be increased, so that it has to complete whatever it's doing, assuming it will recover.

If anyone has another way to work with huge autogenerated files, I'd be willing to try them. Obviously, spending hours manually breaking up the file is not an option and my attempts to split the file into multiple files using partial classes simply wouldn't compile (as I recall, the error was that it ran out of string space - presumably, VS couldn't maintain all the cross-file information for over two thousand partial classes in its internal structures).

Comment: Restarting automatically sounds like a crash; if it's just hung, you should get prompted to wait or kill the process.  Can you see whether there are any crash events in your Event Viewer?  If so, I suggest sending feedback through VS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to close the large file window immediately on opening to prevent Visual Studio from processing it. For example in a [IVsRunningDocTableEvents.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdoctableevents.onbeforedocumentwindowshow?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsRunningDocTableEvents_OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow_System_UInt32_System_Int32_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsWindowFrame_) handler:

```
public int OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
{
    try
    {
        if (GetDocumentName(docCookie).EndsWith(fileToBlock, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            pFrame.CloseFrame((int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.__FRAMECLOSE.FRAMECLOSE_NoSave);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
    }
    return Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

See [Block certain file from opening in a document tab](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#BlockFile) sample extension for Visual Commander.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the forums on MSDN I was able to find a high number of people with the same issue you're reporting. The VS Development team said they've fixed those issues back in August 2017.

You could try to update Visual Studio and get the release with the fix or try disabling diagnostics tools and elapsed time PerfTip:

[image]

If your project is compatible with VS 2015, I'd suggest going back to it if you still have a working license.

Source:

[Slow IDE when Diagnostics Tools is turned on](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40275/slow-ide-performance-working-with-web-projects-whe.html)

[Slow IDE when CodeLens is turned on](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40277/slow-ide-performance-working-with-web-projects-whe-2.html)

[Slow IDE when fusion logging is turned on](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40276/slow-ide-performance-working-with-web-projects-whe-1.html)

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.6 is the latest version as of 20th Feb 2017. At least, the update installer doesn't offer a later one. The same issue occurs with the same file in VS2015. I haven't tried VS2013 and currently don't have VS2010 installed, but can't imagine they'd be any better.

Comment: I'll dig in a bit more. I'm experiencing some crazy bugs on VS 2017.